# How do I query the records inside the recycle bin using workbench?

Tags: recycle

I deleted a product I created but cannot find it in the product table or recycle bin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To query the record, you need to use "queryAll" instead of "query." If you've already emptied your recycle bin, your record is gone forever. You won't be able to use queryAll in the Developer Console, but in Apex Code, you can use the ALL ROWS keywords:

```
Product2[] deletedProducts = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE ALL ROWS];
```

To do so in the Workbench, set "Deleted and archived records:" to "Include".

[image: QueryMore in Workbench]